# Add license button disappear on Vuforia License activation

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to activate a Vuforia License in my unity project, But when i paste my license key in the "App license key " bar the "Add license " button disappears.

could someone explain me how to fix this issue

Comment: Isn't that the expected behavior? It's the same for me. Are you actually not able to use Vuforia then? Because for me it works like that. "Add License" will lead you to Vuforias Dev Portal to actually create/add a new one which you don't want as you already have one. Just paste yours in and you should be good to go:)

Comment: @anjelomerte I am new to vuforia , i am following a tutorial. In that tutorial after pasting the lisence key into the box , "Add licence" is still there , when I try to troubleshoot, it say this behaviour may happen due to incorrect licence key. But i copied the licence key for the web , so there is no chace that the key is wrong .

Comment: @anjelomerte so did they remove the add licence button in the latest version?

Comment: @anjelomerte assume they changed the way license work , but once I use my licence key vuforia in any engine , it will be upadated in my vuforia licence page . Here it isn't happening . So i think the vuforia licence isn't activated properly.

Comment: So After pasting your key you are not able to use Vuforia features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add License` button is there to quickly open the Vuforia Developer Portal page to allow you to create a license key if you don't have one yet.

After you create a license key, copy-paste it into the `VuforiaConfiguration`'s  `App License Key` field and your project will be ready to use all the Vuforia features included in your license. No further step is needed to activate the license.

If you encounter any issue, please feel free to create a new Issue in Vuforia's public GitHub repository: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues.

Additionally, it is strongly recommended to not share your license key publicly. I would suggest you to delete the link to the picture in your question and create a new one before you continue developing with Vuforia Engine.